# NGINX Refusing Connection on SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

Got a problem where when I try to access https://betterexaminations.ie, I get connection refused, but when I try by the ip, it works fine, (https://) 46.137.41.29.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Here my nginx config:

```
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    passenger_root /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12;
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.8;
        server {
                listen 443;
                server_name betterexaminations.ie;
                root /var/rails/papers/public/;
                passenger_enabled on;
                ssl on;
                ssl_certificate /var/rails/papers/certs/csr/thawte/certificate.bundle.cert;
                ssl_certificate_key /var/rails/papers/certs/csr/www.betterexaminations.ie.key;
                ssl_verify_depth 3;

        }       



        server {
                listen 80;
                server_name betterexaminations.ie;
                root /var/rails/papers/public/;
                passenger_enabled on;
        }    
}
```

I get no interesting errors in Nginx logs or rails logs.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
nmap -sT -r -n -p443 betterexaminations.ie
```

outputs:

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-11-29 01:01 UTC
Nmap scan report for betterexaminations.ie (46.137.41.29)
Host is up (0.0022s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds
```

Comment: Define "interesting". What -do- you get? Anything?

Comment: I mean that there's nothing related to the attempted connection in the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNS is not configured properly:

```
$ host -t A betterexaminations.ie
betterexaminations.ie has address 54.247.125.236
```

Now it seems ok:

```
$ host -t A betterexaminations.ie
betterexaminations.ie has address 46.137.41.29
```

The certificate seems ok:

```
$ echo ""|openssl s_client -connect 46.137.41.29:443|openssl x509 -subject -issuer -dates -noout
depth=2 C = US, O = "thawte, Inc.", OU = Certification Services Division, OU = "(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN = thawte Primary Root CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
DONE
subject= /OU=Go to https://www.thawte.com/repository/index.html/OU=Thawte SSL123 certificate/OU=Domain Validated/CN=betterexaminations.ie
issuer= /C=US/O=Thawte, Inc./OU=Domain Validated SSL/CN=Thawte DV SSL CA
notBefore=Nov 17 00:00:00 2012 GMT
notAfter=Nov 17 23:59:59 2013 GMT
```

Comment: It was pointing to 54.247.125.236. Now it is ok. Seems that you have fixed it.